How to debug Powershell Script in Deno Source Code
I am exploring Deno 2.0, am following their documentation, and their given Powershell command is failing:
deno completions powershell >> $profile

out-file : Could not find a part of the path
'C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1'.
I am using VSCode, have cloned the deno repo, setup Rust, and would like to debug/step through the code that the above Powershell script uses (location: cli/args/flags.rs). How can I set a breakpoint in VSCode and have it hit, given that it is initialized through the PowerShell command line?
EDIT2: I am not asking to fix the error, per se. I know how to attach a debugger to VSCode. I have successfully debugged both Rust / Deno / Typescript code in the past. What I am having an issue with is "connecting" my breakpoints in VSCode Deno Source Code and the completely separate window that is PowerShell (where I actually run the deno script that launches Deno).

deno is an executable, not a PowerShell command, so you just attach whatever debugger you would have attached to any other rust binary :)

I am able to debug my own code in Deno. My confusion stems from this: if I was writing an app, I'd follow my code into the Deno source code with ctrl-left-click definition. Here though, I have added no code, and I have no idea how to "connect" putting a breakpoint in the Deno source code while initializing it through command line.

From the documentation Configure PowerShell shell completion: deno completions powershell | Out-String | Invoke-Expression. If you want to inspect the completion source instead of evaluating it, you can simply redirect it to a file, etc. If this answers your question, I can write it as one — if not, can you [edit] the question to clarify?

I have read the docs, am aware of your piece of code, having already run it successfully in the past. My main question revolves not around fixing the error I'm getting, per se. My primary goal is to debug and walk through the source code of the Deno program.

^ @The-Stanislav Deno consists of source code in multiple languages: Rust and JavaScript — if you want to debug the Rust source, then you'd recompile it (targeting a debug build) just like any other Rust program, and if you want to debug the JS, then you can use the built-in VS Code JS debugger. Is there something that differentiates this question from others asking about how to debug Rust or JS code?

Yet again - I am not asking how to debug standard Rust code, or standard Deno code. I know how to attach a debugger to VSCode. I am not sure how to make the subtlety any clearer. I will edit the question again and put in bold certain points. Perhaps it will help.

As an aside, re the specific error at hand: It is PowerShell complaining that it cannot perform the >> redirection, not the deno CLI. Not only does the specific file pointed to by $PROFILE not exist by default, neither does its directory, which causes the error you saw. Additionally, the use of >> instead of | Add-Content risks corruption of a preexisting $PROFILE file due to potentially mixing encodings, and the syntax .$profile is treacherous, because the lack of a space after . only happens to work because the operand starts with $. Worth giving them feedback.
